# Not able to view Data Hub Importer Configuration

Tags: pimcore, pimcore-datahub

I am newbie in Pimcore and i am trying to install pimcore, datahub importor for my usercases to explore

1. I have installed Pimcore using below link which is successful  [Docker Based Installlation](https://pimcore.com/docs/platform/Pimcore/Getting_Started/Installation/Docker_Based_Installation)
2. Installed datahub in current instance pimcore using this document [Datahub Installation](https://pimcore.com/docs/platform/Datahub/Installation_and_Upgrade/)
3. I am trying to install datahub importer in current instance pimcore using this document [Datahub importer](https://pimcore.com/docs/platform/Data_Importer/Installation)
4. I can see the PimcoreDataImporterBundle and PimcoreDataHubBundle bundles are installed but i cannot able to see the datahub importer config option when i login using admin access

[image]
[image]

Can you guys help what i am missing here to configure datahub importer?